# Shell Script inside perl script

Tags: perl, shell

I have a perl script which is working  fine, but then I wanted to add some shell script in it. I tried to google but I don't know the exact word. Is it embedded programming?
So this is what I know.

We can write assembly code in a C file like this:

```
*****
C - code
int a=10;
char *p;
asm {       //here is the secondary or embedded language (assembly code)
assembly code...
ldaa 1;
push;
}

back to C...
print( "this works");
```

I just want to do something along these lines, but with perl as the main language and shell script being the secondary or embedded language.

Thank you everyone

Comment: You could construct a string that had valid shell commands in it then use `system` to execute them: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$exec_string = <<EXEC;
echo this is my shell script
ls > tmp1
ls > tmp2
EXEC

system($exec_string)
```

`EXEC` can be substituted by any word (e.g. SHELL, SCRIPT, whatever).

Comment: and $exec_string is just another perl variable here?

Comment: Yes, you can use it like any other scalar.

Comment: and one last thing...is this called embedded shell script or somethins else?

Comment: @sush basically you are just creating a multi-line string, storing it in a variable and executing it. You can do whatever you want with this string - e.g. you can print it instead of executing it.

Comment: yes but i just want to know what the process is called...so people understand me when I open my mouth

Comment: thanks for your feedback...I will highlight your answer as soon as I check it with my code :)

Comment: @sush I think it is just called executing a system (or shell) command.

Comment: @sush First part is using a here-doc to put the script in a variable, second part is calling the [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) built-in function.

Comment: For more information on here-docs, check `perldoc perlop` or read online [here.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)